# Can an Application Establish a Websocket Connection Over Port 80 Along With IIS Running?

Tags: unity-game-engine, iis, websocket, network-programming

We are developing a multi-user VR system using Unity and have run into the following problem:

#### Configuration

The configuration is as follows:

- Website – To be published on our server using IIS for Viewers to watch Presenters using their browsers.
- VR Application – Run remotely by Presenters on dedicated laptops. Presenters use VR Headsets to explore an environment and share it with Viewers. Presenters connect to Host Application and establish a websocket connection using port 80.
- Host Application – To run on our server for relaying websocket communication between all VR Presenters and browser Viewers.

#### Problem

When we run the Host application on our server the networking code failed to listen on port 80 for traffic. The error was: `"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"`. It appears that IIS, or perhaps the system, has taken full control of port 80 and preventing another resource from using it.

#### Constraints

Our client's network security constraints prevent us introducing a second server to run the Host Application (they can only connect to a defined list of IP addresses) and they cannot open new ports for us. So we have a single server (Windows Server 2016) and port 80 to play with!

Is it remotely possible to publish websites using IIS (HTTP port 80) AND run an application which listens and communicates websocket traffic also on port 80?

#### Development Information

During development we setup a second server and when we located the Host Application on this (everything still port 80) everything worked. This development server wasn't running IIS, just the Host Application. For the testing we could use our own computers and didn't have the IP constraints so we could point the browsers and Presenter laptops to the development server for websocket traffic.

#### Summary

Any thoughts, advise or guidance would be very welcome as currently we don't know which way to turn!

Comment: I thinks you can use nginx instead of IIS to publise the sever or use other port like 90 rather than the same port of the http

Comment: Thanks. While we may be able to open another port on our server I don't think our client's will be able to establish a websocket connection because their ports are very locked down.

Comment: Okey, you can refer to my answer, two different port and using nginx to combine into port 80, thus, it is just port 80 for the public

Comment: Interesting. I know nothing about nginx so forgive my basic question. IIS on our server is hosting several websites. Are you suggesting that HTTP traffic to and from IIS remains on port 80 and websocket traffic (flowing through port 80 to the client) is re-directed to another port which my Host Application is using?

Comment: oh, my suggestions is: Try to avoid using the same port or using `nginx's reverse proxy` for load balancing, otherwise the port may be blocked.

Comment: Is it possible for us to change our Host Application to listen internally on, say, port 7777 and then using nginx listen on port 80 for incoming traffic directed to our Host Application and re-route it to port 7777. We would then have to perform the reverse to re-route 7777 back to 80 for outbound traffic?

Comment: Yep, it named `Reverse proxy` of nginx

Comment: I will research this. If anyone can suggest a good resource for understanding how to set it up I would be grateful.

Comment: You have to reveal some code. If your code binds to TCP directly, then port conflict cannot be resolved, but if your code binds to HTTP/WebSockets, then it can share the port with IIS with some extra Windows HTTP API settings.

Comment: That's intriguing. Its a very simple Unity multi-player server using Mirror's `Simple Web Transport` [Mirror](https://mirror-networking.com/docs/Articles/Transports/SimpleWebTransport.html). When running it listens, handshakes and establishes websocket communications with clients. Needing to use port 80 to satisfy our client's security constraints it is conflicting with IIS.

Comment: Well, based on its source code https://github.com/MirrorNetworking/SimpleWebTransport/blob/master/source/Server/WebSocketServer.cs#L38 the port conflict cannot be resolved (`TcpListener` binds to TCP port 80 directly, bypassing Windows HTTP API).

Comment: I don't see the direct connection to Unity3d here .. sounds more like a server side issue

Comment: There are a lot of resources in google about the nginx

Comment: Thank you everyone who suggested solutions and spent time answering. Please see my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

1. use another two port to published server and ws(e.g. 90 and 91), and use `nginx`(or apache?) to do the diversion according to the agreement from port 80, you can use the code like

```
# code in nginx
location / {#http
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host  $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:90;# real port of server
            proxy_redirect default;
            #root   html;
            #index  index.html index.htm;
        }
       location /ws{#ws
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            client_max_body_size 10m;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:91;# real port of ws
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
            proxy_read_timeout 300s;
            proxy_send_timeout 300s; 
       }
```

detail is in [here](https://blog.csdn.net/nfq6612/article/details/88555092)(PS: it is in Chinese) and plz care of the port `443`(https and wss)

2. use other port

Comment: Thank you. Our client's network is very secure and they will not allow a connection through a new port which we provide which is why I am trying to use port 80 for both ws traffic as well as the HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the same port can handle multiple different protocols, and websocket is an upgrade based on the http protocol.

But this is not recommended, because it may have some problems.

- A port can only be monitored by one process, and port 80 in IIS is
  monitored by w3svc. The server must take a certain method to detect
  the protocol sent by the client. Once more protocols may be used in
  the port, it will increase consumption.
- Server can't support multiple    protocols where the server speaks
  first, because there is no way to    detect the protocol of the
  client. You can support a single    server-first protocol with
  multiple client-first protocols (by adding    a short delay after
  accept to see if the client will send data), but    that's a bit
  wonky.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps others who also want to run an application on their server but find it cannot listen on port 80/443 because port 80/443 has been reserved for IIS. I finally solved the problem as follows:

I created a new Domain and pointed it to my webserver. I then created a new Website in IIS bound to my new Domain. I pointed the Website to an empty folder. I then downloaded and installed Microsoft's URL Rewrite extension for IIS along with the Application Request Routing extension:

- [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
- [Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing)

After these were installed I could select my new Website in IIS and in the IIS section to the right double-click the new URL Rewrite option. An Add Rule dialog appears and I could select a Reverse Proxy option and create a simple rule to re-direct traffic to `localhost:80` and back again for outbound traffic. Incredibly, it worked!

I'm just a developer trying to wrestle a complex project towards delivery so this may have its flaws or you may know of a better solution, but for me I can now move on.